# Having and error with dart2js as a result of dash_chat

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

dart2js error with dash_chat

One of our existing applications makes use of dash_chat, which is working on a V2, however, v2 has a fraction of the APIs implemented. The project is somewhat dormant so today we just doing housekeeping and trying to keep the project up-to-date.

I am now getting this error, and sadly I went and updated all packages and we are using FLutter 3 and Dart 2.17 in all our other projects.

`Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.`

So not sure which of the many things I changed is ultimately the cause of this issue, which crops up when trying to build for web.

No relevant issues on the DC repo and google is being very unhelpful on this one, was hoping someone had some insight that would allow me to take the correct steps forward (or back if need be) to get around this.

TIA